# Android SQLITE : Get Id value based on column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building my first android app where I am trying to sync mysql data to sqlite in android.  I have two tables in mysql and both gets synced properly into android sqlite.  The first table is as follows:

```
id ProjectName
1  RA_Tesco
2  RA_Coors
3  RA_JWNT
```

The second table is as follows:

```
id pid Outlet Add1
1   1   Tesco  XYZ
2   1   Tesco  ABC
3   2   Coors  NBC
```

The PID in second table references to id of first table.  How can I subset the second table based on PID value derived from id of first table.  I know it is pretty straight forward in php or mysql or even in Python or R.  However, fetching the id based on string and referencing the same in the second table seems quite tricky in Android.  My codes so far:

```
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
clickedId = getIntent().getExtras().get("clickedId").toString();
```

When I toast clickedId, I get the correct string, for example, `RA_Tesco`.

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME1+" where pid = 1"+"", null);
```

The above code also renders the correct set of records from the sqlite table.  I am struggling with integrating them both.  I tried the following:

```
String pid;
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
clickedId = getIntent().getExtras().get("clickedId").toString();
pid = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery( "select id from "+sqLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" where projectName = "+clickedId+"", null );
```

I am getting `incompatible types` error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
clickedId = getIntent().getExtras().get("clickedId").toString();
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME1+" where pid = (select id from "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+ " where ProjectName = '"+clickedId+"'"+")", null);
```

I just followed the same MySQL principle of nesting queries.  The above code roughly reads as follows:

```
select * from table2 where pid = (select id from table1 where projectname="xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try put your query to single quote

2) `rawQuery` returns `Cursor`, not `String`

So,

```
Cursor pidCursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery( "select id from "+sqLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" where projectName = '"+clickedId+"'", null );
```

Comment: Thank you will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the corresponding rows from the 2nd table when you pass as an argumnent the value of a `ProjectName` (I guess this is `clickedId` although its name is id?), create a statement like this:

```
String sql = 
    "select t2.* from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME1 + 
    " t2 inner join " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + 
    " t1 on t1.id = t2.pid where t1.ProjectName = ?";
```

This joins the 2 tables and returns all the columns of the 2nd table. 
The execute `rawQuery()` by passing `clickedId` as a parameter, which is the proper way to avoid sql injection:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {clickedId});
```